# Removing /api part from WebAPI path using a Reverse Proxy i.c.w. Swashbuckle

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, reverse-proxy, swashbuckle

I am trying to configure an IIS hosted DotNet WebAPI with Swaschbuckle behind an Apache Reverse Proxy.

Desired public urls should look something like:

- http://sub.domain.com/SomeAPI/Controller/Method
- http://sub.domain.com/SomeAPI/swagger

Target urls look like:

- http://machine/SomeAPI/api/Controller/Method
- http://machine/SomeAPI/swagger

Notice that I am trying to remove the /api part.
Is there any way I can make Swashbuckle know about this redirection?

Comment: What does your route config look like in the WebApiConfig.cs file? Once routing is in place, Swashbuckle will pick this up since it uses reflection to find all the routes.

Comment: `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );`

Comment: And this is on some of the controller methods `[Route("api/SomeController/SomeMethod")]`

Comment: But the thing is, I want to know if I can configure Swaschbuckle in such a way, that is generates the documentation with URL's such as the ones exposed by the reverse proxy. I do not want to change the routing.

Comment: Did you ever figure out anything around this? I'm coming across a similar issue with a asp.net core 2.1 application.

Comment: In the end I decided to just remove the /api part from all my routes.